# getting android uuid inside singleton

Tags: android

I have to get Android UUID in **several parts** of my application. I do it like that

```
Settings.Secure.getString(mcontext.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)
```

Is there a sense to realize this logic inside singleton? And is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Helper class and static method:

```
public class Helper {

public static String getUuid(Context context) {
    return Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
}}
```

Then you can use it like

```
Helper.getUuid(context);
```

Comment: So that way I will call that method each time I need UUID. Right?